# column specification timestap not recoginse in create table

Tags: hive

I  have issue to reading avro file, i have timestamp column name in schema file

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sampe_table 
(
username string,
tweet string,
`timestamp` long
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS AVRO 
LOCATION 'hdfs:////user/hive/warehouse/avrodata/'
```

Error
AILED: ParseException line 5:12 cannot recognize input near 'long' ')' 'STORED' in column type
also i set `SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;`
but still i have error

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't have **`Long`** type.

Use **`Bigint`**..etc datatype instead of **long**.

***HiveDDL:***

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sampe_table 
(
username string,
tweet string,
`timestamp` bigint
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS AVRO 
LOCATION 'hdfs:////user/hive/warehouse/avrodata/';
```

Refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes) link for more details regards to all supported types in Hive.